# React - How do i set one button to change its colour and the other buttons another colour instead of all having the same colour?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made a quiz app where when the user clicks an answer button where case 1 is the user clicks the correct answer button and it turns green and where case 2 is the user clicks the wrong answer and it turns red while the correct answer will be shown in green. However, from what i made, i made all the buttons turn either red ( if user picks the wrong answer ) or turns green ( if user picks the correct answer ). Why it is like this is because i was testing and playing around with it but now im not sure how to change it.

Here's my code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import styles from '@component/styles/Home.module.css'
import { shuffleArray } from "./Helper";

export default function ShowQuestions() {

    const [data, setData] = useState(null);
    const [quesno, setQuesno] = useState(0);
    const [answersArr, setAnswersArr] = useState([]);
    const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
    const [able, setAble] = useState(false);
    const [styleButton, setStyleButton] = useState(styles.answerbutton);
    const [score, setScore] = useState(0);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function getData() {
          let res = await fetch(`https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10`);
          let body = await res.json();
          setData(body.results);
        }
        
        getData();
      }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (data) {
            setLoading(true);
            const newAnswersArr = [];
            newAnswersArr.push(data[quesno].correct_answer);
            const incorrectAnswers = data[quesno].incorrect_answers;
            for (let i = 0; i < incorrectAnswers.length; i++) {
                newAnswersArr.push(data[quesno].incorrect_answers[i]);
            }

            const shuffledArray = shuffleArray(newAnswersArr);
            setAnswersArr(shuffledArray);
        }

    }, [data, quesno]);
    
    

    function nextQuestion() {
        if (quesno < data.length - 1) {
            setQuesno(quesno + 1);
            setMessage("");
            setAble(false);
            setStyleButton(styles.answerbutton);
        }
    } 
    function checkAnswer(answer) {
        let correctIndex = answersArr.indexOf(data[quesno].correct_answer);
        for (let i = 0; i < answersArr.length; i++) {
            if (answersArr[i] === answer) {
                if (i === correctIndex) {
                    setMessage("Correct Answer!");
                    setScore(score + 1);
                    setStyleButton(styles.correctanswer);
                    
                } else {
                    setMessage("WRONG!!!!");
                    setStyleButton(styles.incorrectanswer);
                }
            }
        }
            setAble(true);
    }

    return (
        <section className={styles.box}>
            <div className={styles.centering}>
                <object type="image/svg+xml" data="/loading.svg" hidden={loading} ></object>
            </div>
            {data && (
                    <>
                        <h3 className={styles.centering}>Marks: {score} /10</h3>
                        <p className={styles.category}>{data[quesno].category}</p>
                        <p className={styles.type}>Type: {data[quesno].type}</p>
                        <p className={styles.difficulty}>Difficulty: {data[quesno].difficulty}</p>
                        <p className={styles.question}>{data[quesno].question}</p>

                        {answersArr.map(answer => (
                            <div className={styles.buttonarrangement}>
                            <button className={styleButton} key={answer} onClick={ () => checkAnswer(answer)} disabled={able} >{answer}</button>
                            </div>
                        ))}
                    </>
                )}

            {message && (
                <h3 className={styles.centering}>{message}</h3>
            )}
            <div className={styles.nextquestion}>
                <button className={styles.nextbutton}  onClick={ () => nextQuestion()}>Next question</button>
            </div>
        </section>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of passing answer, pass the element (the button that the user just clicked) and the index of the answer.

**inside return**

```js
...
{
  answersArr.map((answer, i) => (
    <div className={styles.buttonarrangement}>
      <button
        className={styleButton}
        key={answer}
        onClick={e => checkAnswer(e.target, i)}
        disabled={able}
      >
        {answer}
      </button>
    </div>
  ));
}
...
```

**checkAnswer function**

```js
function checkAnswer(btn, i) {
  let correctIndex = answersArr.indexOf(data[quesno].correct_answer);
  if (correctIndex === i) {
    setMessage("Correct Answer!");
    setScore(score + 1);
    btn.classList.add(styles.correctanswer);
  } else {
    setMessage("WRONG!!!!");
    btn.classList.add(styles.incorrectanswer);
  }
  setAble(true);
}
```